# Is it possible to dynamically change an url with values in the array without storing the values in separate feature file

Tags: testing, cucumber, karate

I need to array values say 10 values from the previous url response to get replace in the next url

*def k = [1,2,3]

Given url 'https://www.' + k + 'zzzz'

Tried this:

*def k = [1,2,3]

Given url 'https://www.' + k[*] + 'zzzz'

Expecting:

Given url 'https://www.+ 1 + zzzz'
need its response to store
Given url 'https://www.+ 2 + zzzz'
need its response to store
Given url 'https://www.+ 3 + zzzz'
need its response to store

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Karate 1.3.1 onwards: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

Try the below and see it work.

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
# do some http stuff here and prepare the data to use in the loop
* def data = [{ myNum: 1 }, { myNum: 2 }, { myNum: 3 }]

Scenario Outline:
* url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${myNum}`
* method get

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |
```