How to call a scenario outline from one feature file to another feature file and use response from each data set as a request in karate
I do have a scenario where I need to call a feature file with multiple scenario outline
Details
Feature File 1:-
Create logins with multiple user data set using csv/data tables
Then set the response as karate.set('loginRespone', response)
Feature File 2:-

def submitLogin = call read (pathtofeature Feature File1)
def loginData = submitLogin.loginRespone

(I suppose it is a JSON array and need to store in JSON object and use forEach function to loop through each response) - But not sure
For each response of data set in loginData

headers
path path
request loginData
method post
status 200


Not sure the solution though, can anyone help please?

I would not recommend 2 back-to-back outlines, try to have one scenario outline that does everything. be aware of the @setup annotation, here are 2 examples: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74785478/143475 and 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673358/143475

Thanks Peter, The intention here is to automate submit operation. I do have create method automated in different feature file but in Submit feature file I want to use the same create tests by calling create feature file to remove the overhead of creating the same users for automating the submit operation in submit feature file. Not sure if there is way to achieve this!
